# How to get ranges of column difference counts using the case statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `users` in which I have only two columns:

- Holiday Allowance (`users.holidayallowance`)
- Remaining Allowance (`users.remaining`)

I want to find out ranges of the difference of these two columns, e.g.

```
+--------------+--------+
| Taken Days   | Ranges |
+--------------+--------+
| 0 - 10       |     13 |
| 11 - 20      |      3 |
| 21 - 30      |      7 |
+--------------+--------+
```

The above table would imply: There are 13 people who have taken 0 - 10 days off, 3 people who have taken 11 -20 days off, 7 who haven't taken 21-30 days off etc.

I have tried out the following query, and I know I'm wrong, so if someone could guide me on this, that would be great. Thank you.

```
SELECT

count( 

CASE 
WHEN holidayallowance - remaining < 10 THEN '0-10'
WHEN holidayallowance - remaining >10 and holidayallowance - remaining < 20 THEN '10 - 20'
when holidayallowance - remaining >20 and holidayallowance - remaining <30 THEN  '20 - 30'
when holidayallowance - remaining >30 and holidayallowance - remaining <40 then  '30 - 40'
END
) AS 'Days Taken Off' FROM `users`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN holidayallowance - remaining < 10 THEN '0-10'
             WHEN holidayallowance - remaining < 20 THEN '10 - 20'
             WHEN holidayallowance - remaining < 30 THEN '20 - 30'
             WHEN holidayallowance - remaining < 40 THEN '30 - 40'
       END) AS Days_Taken_Off,
      COUNT(*)
FROM `users`
GROUP BY Days_Taken_Off;
```

Note:  I have changed the logic as well.  The first matching condition is the one that is used for the result.  So, you can just "chain" the conditions together as inequalities.  (In practice, this makes it much easier to change the boundaries.)

Comment: I would use a `BETWEEN` also in the cases to make it cleaner - though it's not necessary.

Comment: @TimothyG. . . . That is unnecessary.  I simplified the logic to just use `<` so the results "chain".

Comment: Looks even better.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, could you edit my question's title so that it suits the context more and is helpful to users looking for something similar?